# How can I change the war name generated by maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven-2

How can I change the name from `1.0.snapshot-jar-with-dependencies` to something else, below are contents of my POM:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.package.example.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Use the following in the configuration of the `maven-assembly-plugin`:

```
<configuration>
  <finalName>custom-name</finalName>
  <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
</configuration>
```

Full details in the official documentation of the [`assembly:single`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) mojo.

Comment: assembly:assembly has been deprecated, please use [assembly:single](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html)

Comment: Also quite useful when using assembly:single with "dir" format descriptor.  Using "." means outputdir specified will be true output dir

Comment: where did you find the information about the `finalName` property ? I didn't see any reference to this property in the documentation http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html

Answer (score 87):

You can achieve this by specifying the `finalName` property in your pom, e.g.

```
<build>
    <finalName>something-else</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: again I get something-else-jar-with-dependencies this worked, how can I get rid of jar-with-dependencies, when I delete descriptorRefs I get build error

Comment: Indeed, you'll need the `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` tag as suggested by Pascal.

Comment: Note, the suffix will be appended to this name.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of packaging a JAR with dependencies, the  won't work. You will fix it by using the dependency plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>project.group.id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
                                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/some/dir</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>custom-name.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```