# Maven: How to rename the war file for the project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project `bird` with the following components in `pom.xml`

```
        <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
        <artifactId>bird</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <name>bird</name>
    
        <modules>
            <module>persistence</module>
            <module>business</module>
            <module>service</module>
            <module>web</module>
        </modules>
```

and the web module `pom.xml`

```
        <parent>
            <artifactId>bird</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
    
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
```

The web module creates a war file named `web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`
How can I configure maven to build it as `bird.war`?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3265544/422353

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can use the following in the web module that produces the war:

```
<build>
  <finalName>bird</finalName>
 . . .
</build>
```

This leads to a file called bird.war to be created when goal "war:war" is used.

Comment: when i compile my project with the name "bird.war" i get a war that is namend "bird.war.war".

Comment: @Kalaschni just use 'bird', not 'bird.war' -- each of the various build plugins adds the appropriate file extension automatically (war, jar, ear)

Comment: Or more generally, we can use : `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>`

Comment: This answer solved my issue where a submodule's war was being generated with the parent's name, which I did not want.  The problem was the <finalName> element was set in the parent POM.  Deleting that element resulted in the war file generated with the correct name of the submodule.

Comment: In IDEA 20156 2.4 I had the additional problem that it kept generating the old war file everytime I tried to deploy on a Payara Glassfish 4.1. When that happens to go to Open Module Settings -> Artifacts -> Output Layout and rename the war file to your desired outcome. I needed this because the context root changes with the war file name in IDEA which is a pain when you have a different configured in .properties file.

Answer (score 33):

You need to configure the war plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warName>bird.war</warName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

More info [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)

Comment: FYI: This answer is no longer valid (since maven-war-plugin version 3.0.0 and onwards). 

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-373.

Comment: <warName> works (at least in war-plugin in 3.2.3) but it always appends "-<classifier>.war"  where <classifier> is empty by default and can be set inside <configuration>.  I use <warName>${project.build.finalName}##${buildDateTimeFile}</warName>  with "buildDateTimeFile" set by build-helper-maven-plugin to get "myApp##2020-05-29_10-24-00.war".   This is especially useful if you create multiple war-files (dev/test/prod) in one go.

Answer (score 14):

Lookup pom.xml > project tag > build tag.

I would like solution below.

```
<artifactId>bird</artifactId>
<name>bird</name>

<build>
    ...
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  OR
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```

Worked for me. ^^

Answer (score 6):

You can follow the below step to modify the .war file name if you are using maven project.

Open pom.xml file of your maven project and go to the tag `<build></build>`,

1. In that give your desired name between this tag :
   `<finalName></finalName>`.

   **ex. : `<finalName>krutik</finalName>`**

   After deploying this .war you will be able to access url with:
   http://localhost:8080/krutik/
2. If you want to access the url with slash **'/'** then you will have
   to specify then name as below:

   **e.x. : `<finalName>krutik#maheta</finalName>`**

   After deploying this .war you will be able to access url with:
   http://localhost:8080/krutik/maheta