# maven adds version number to war - won't deploy

Tags: java, maven, build, jboss7.x

I'm using maven to build a war file for JBOSS AS 7.  After a maven deploy, there is 'test.war' in the local repository, and a 'test-2.war' in the remote repository.  This is all as expected (2 is the version in the POM).

If I manually deploy the 'test.war', everything works fine.  If I deploy 'test-2.war' the deployment fails. If I rename 'test-2.war' to be 'test.war', the deployment works but trying to access it in a browser fails with error:

```
type Status report

message /test/Test

description The requested resource (/test/Test) is not available.
```

Since both war files are the result of the same maven build and deploy, why doesn't renaming the -2 version work the same as the first?

Is there a way I can deploy the -2 version without renaming, or what can I do to force the build so that I can rename the -2 version and have it deploy?

I know I can use maven's jboss deploy, but that's not an option in my case.  I need the war file from the remote repository for manual deployments.

EDIT:  The basic question here is why can't I rename the file {artifactId}-{version}.war to just {artifactId}.war and have it deploy in JBoss AS 7 properly?

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the war like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warName>bird.war</warName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

OR

```
<build>
  <finalName>bird.war</finalName>
 . . .
</build>
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488509/maven-how-to-rename-the-war-file-for-the-project/14488602#14488602)

Comment: I'm using <finalName>, which is why the local repository has the name test.war.  From what I've read, both of the suggestions (warName and finalName) don't impact the remote repository.  My experience confirms this.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a jboss-web.xml? And setting the context-root there as "test"?

Comment: yes, I tried using a jboss-web.xml file with <context-root>test</context-root>, didn't help.