# How can I prevent mvn install from creating WEB-INF/lib & classes? Or why would I want it?

Tags: java, angularjs, maven

I have been working on inherited code for a few days now and am trying to get a grasp of how maven works and why the project is configured as it is. The project uses Jetty as an http-server, and serves up an Angular app, in addition to using Jersey to provide RESTful endpoints for the Angular app. The project directory is:

```
src
    main
        config
        java
            Java code, including Jetty server
        webapp
            WEB-INF
                web.xml
            index.html and all things Angular are also in this directory
```

As part of the deployment process, I was told to set up maven such that the project is packaged as a .war. To do that, I have the following:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exploded</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib</packagingExcludes>
            <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
            <warName>${project.name}</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I run `mvn install`, the following two are generated within my `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` : `lib/` and `classes/`. Now when I run the project, I have conflicts at the Java level, I have discovered that the cause of the problem was the fact that these two new directories now exist in my `target/classes/WEB-INF`. Removing them and running: `target/classes/com.../Root.class` fixes the problem. But if `target/classes/WEB-INF/classes/com.../Root.class` is present, the project starts throwing exceptions at run time. Without diving into the low level exceptions themselves, can someone explain why I would / wouldn't want `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` to be generated for me, and if I wouldn't want them, how can I disable their creation in maven?

EDIT: I have since found that replacing `webappDirectory` attribute with `webXml` attribute will prevent the copying of `lib/` and `classes/`, however, I am still not clear why I would want those directories there in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven operates on a "Convention over Configuration" philosophy.

Your desire to have a WebApp that doesn't follow convention is causing you the problems you are having.

Comment out the ENTIRE `<plugin>` element for your `maven-war-plugin`, ensure that you have `<packaging>war</packaging>` setup, and then you'll get the "Convention" part of the equation.

A WebApp that is built as a WAR file with all of the dependencies included (like the Servlet spec about WebApp define).

The `WEB-INF/lib` is the lookup location for all dependencies that your webapp needs.  Be it in the WAR file format, or in the exploded format.

However, you seem to want an exploded WAR file from maven, not sure why, as that has no benefit during a build anymore. (you can use default war behavior and the various web container maven plugins to just run the webapp in an embedded container of your choice, directly from maven)

If you insist on exploded, consider this advice:

- Make sure your `<packaging>war</packaging>` is set on your `<project>`
- Read the documentation on [`maven-war-plugin:exploded`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html)
- The only reason to exclude `WEB-INF/lib` from a war file is if your WAR file has no jar file dependencies.  If that's the case, then you should just specify the correct `<scope>` values for your `<dependency>` to keep them from being included in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.
- The `<webappDirectory>` configuration element is your OUTPUT directory, where the built WAR file contents are generated and produced. (don't specify this configuration value, leave it as default)
- The `<warSourceDirectory>` is your INPUT directory, where your files that are not compiled classes, classpath resources, or dependencies/libraries come from. (don't specify this configuration value, leave it as default)
- The `<warName>` element is not used, its invalid.
- Specify a [`<build><finalName>` for configuring the war filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488676/775715) to suit yourself.

In short, you don't need the `<configuration>` section for your `maven-war-plugin`.