# Issue in Changing the war file name generated by maven

Tags: maven, war

I just followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488509/maven-how-to-rename-the-war-file-for-the-project) and modified my pom to create different war file. Here is the original configuration

```
<build>

    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Run with Jetty -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Compile java -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Build war -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Pack zips -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>webapp</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>LabSystem${packname}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/webapp.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the Modified (want to create Cambellton.war)

```
<build>

    <finalName>Cambellton</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Run with Jetty -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Compile java -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Build war -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Pack zips -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>webapp</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>Cambellton{packname}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/webapp.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When try to build, it gives error, but war file is created. I think it giving problem when trying to create the zip file. Here is the error message

```
> [INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ LabSystem ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [LabSystem] in [F:\MyDocuments\Java\ZK7LabSystem\LabSystem\LabSystem\target\Cambellton]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [F:\MyDocuments\Java\ZK7LabSystem\LabSystem\LabSystem\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [4554 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: F:\MyDocuments\Java\ZK7LabSystem\LabSystem\LabSystem\target\Cambellton.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2:single (webapp) @ LabSystem ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/webapp.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.543s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 17 11:29:29 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/348M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2:single (webapp) on project LabSystem: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: F:\MyDocuments\Java\ZK7LabSystem\LabSystem\LabSystem\target\LabSystem.war isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

EDIT 1

Here is the webapp.xml

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>webapp</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/${project.artifactId}/src</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/${project.artifactId}/WebContent</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

EDIT 2 :
Added $ symbol also, but still gives same error
As

```
<build>

        <finalName>$Cambellton</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Run with Jetty -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compile java -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build war -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Pack zips -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webapp</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>Cambellton${packname}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/webapp.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can you post your webapp.xml file also?

Comment: Added the webapp.xml file and added $

Comment: i updated my answer, the error was most probably in the webapp.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Maven Assembly Plugin configuration, check the

```
<finalName>Cambellton{packname}</finalName>
```

the `{packname}` is not recognized as a property because missing the `$` prefix. Assuming that you define `packname` as a property in your pom.

In your original configuration, it was

```
<finalName>LabSystem${packname}</finalName>
```

Also check consistency with your `src/main/assembly/webapp.xml` file, which could include any or the specified generated war file, as below example:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>zip</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.war</include>
      </includes>
      <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**Update**
Base on your latest edits (adding the assembly configuration), I see several things which could be improved and the potential cause of error as well:

- Your file defined in the source element is  using the artifactId of the project, but you renamed it to be `Cambellton`, so you should also make it consistent with this change (`${project.build.directory}/Cambellton.war` instead of `${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war`). This was causing the build error most probably
- Instead of pointing to `/${project.artifactId}/src` I would replace it by `${project.basedir}/src` (same for `WebContent` output directory)