# Maven Install adds version id in final name of the war file

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am beginner with maven.
I have a pom file something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artID</artifactId>
    <version>${FILE_VERSION}</version>
...
```

When the install command is run, I get example_dir/1.0.1/application-1.0.1.war 
I want to retain version in directory structure but I want to remove the version from war file name.
Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven: How to rename the war file for the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488509/maven-how-to-rename-the-war-file-for-the-project)

Comment: Does't work for me :(

Comment: The `${FILE_VERSION}` will not work!

Comment: ${FILE_VERSION} works fine. FILE_VERSION is a variable passed by Jenkins Job.
It does create directory structure as app/1.01/ and a car file app-1.0.1.car

Answer (score 0):

The structure in the local repository (usually `.m2/repository`) is fixed and cannot be changed.

If you need a different name, you need to rename the file after downloading it from the local repository.

Comment: I dont want to change the directory structure. I just want to rename the war file.

Comment: The file names in the directory are also fixed.