# Java webapp to Tomcat 8 running in Docker container at localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

For my spring mvc app I use `docker-compose.yml`

```html
db:  
  build: ./db
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes_from:
    - app-db-data

app-web:  
  build: ./web
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  links:
    - db

app-db-data:  
  image: cogniteev/echo
  command: echo 'Data Container for PostgreSQL'
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

With two Dockerfiles

1. ./web

```html
    FROM tomcat:8-jre8
    MAINTAINER Sergii D

    ADD MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

2. ./db

```html
FROM postgres:9.3  
MAINTAINER Sergii D

ENV POSTGRES_USER admin  
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD pass  
ENV POSTGRES_DB mydb
```

First I do `docker-compose build`

Second `docker-compose up`

After that, app work incorrect at the http://192.168.99.100:8080/MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

but I need use http://localhost:8080/ as root

How I must configure tomcat?

Comment: It sounds like you're using Maven to build the WAR. You can configure Maven to change the name of the WAR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265544/how-can-i-change-the-war-name-generated-by-maven-assembly-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename "MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" to ROOT.war and add it to image. Your app will be available by http://192.168.99.100:8080/

Also http://localhost:8080/ will be available.

Comment: In my docker file I do as you say `ADD ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As I know you have few solutions. 
The `"/MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/"` is actually your **context path** where your application was deployed.

- You can rename your war file to `ROOT.war` but this solution is little bit tricky and I would not vote for this.
- The better solution is to have `ROOT.xml`file and add it to tomcat configuration.

so you can add following to your `Dockerfile` definition

```
 COPY ./ROOT.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
```

and the content of `ROOT.xml` should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context 
  docBase="/opt/webapps/MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" />
```

Since you have mapping ports from docker container to host in `docker-compose` with `"ports"` you can access to backend through `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: "You can rename your war file to ROOT.war but this solution is little bit tricky and I would not vote for this." Because he's using Maven it's actually really easy.

Comment: what exactly is "this" :) Which one did u try?

Comment: @VladoDemcak Both

Comment: @SergiiDiukarev Could you provide your actual `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @VladoDemcak it's actual in first post